# NetBeans 7.1 - unable change to UI language

Tags: netbeans

I installed NetBeans 7.1 and can't change UI language. I didn't find any option for it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

**--locale** on some Windows platforms **makes netbeans crash.** Preffer to use  "-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"

1. Find netbeans etc, likely at the C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.3\etc
2. Open netbeans.conf
3. Find netbeans_default_options
4. Add those options, so:
   netbeans_default_options="blablabla -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US"
5. Save file
6. Restart/start netbeans.

https://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/set_netbeans_user_interface_language

Comment: Just in case you're using a newer version, it still works on 8.2. Thx

Answer (score 9):

You may start with the `--locale en:US` option which sets the interface language.

See the documentation for `--locale language[:country[:variant]] : Use the specified locale` here http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqStartupParameters

Comment: There is one important notice for Windows users: you SHOULD place `--locale en:US` parameter AFTER the closing quotes of the command. You will get an error message if you do it within the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems saving the file:

1. Transfer the netbeans.conf file to your desktop;
2. Windows is gonna say you need permission from the administrator,  press ok;
3. Open the netbeans.conf file that is on your desktop WITH NOTEPAD and make the alterations sugested in the video;
4. Save;
5. Transfer the file back to etc. folder
6. Open NetBeans IDE