# Unable Change Language Or Font of Netbeans in windows 7

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have Netbeans 7.0.1 on Windows 7. I used it last 2 years. But suddenly i seen changes in netbeans language and font patteren before 2 days ago. I tried many thing or change netbeans.cfg file, but still i have probel in nebeans IDE. Here i attached screen shoot of netbeans ide which is installed in my Pc. I also uninstall netbeans, Java or JDK and then install all things , but stile problem is not solve. So any one have suggestion or any idea about that than please help me.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding "--locale en_US" to the *netbeans_default_options* value in 
/etc/netbeans.conf 
should solve your problem.

Comment: You said you uninstalled ide..when installing the new one have you downloaded in the corect language format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386057/netbeans-7-1-unable-change-to-ui-language