# Netbeans can pull but not push to Github: "authentication not supported"

Tags: git, netbeans, github, push, pull

I used to use Github without any problems on my previous PC. Now, on my new PC, I installed the same NB version (8.0.2) and cloned the same project on Github. It can pull updates but when I try to push I receive the error "authentication not supported". I tried disabling windows firewall but it did not work.

It is not about my Github settings since I can push on other computers. Also I am not using a proxy, I have the same connection and IP as before. Only change is moving from Win 7 to 8.1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is late, but somebody may still have problems like me.
The problem is because netbeans uses your computer locale settings.

Aplly this answer [NetBeans 7.1 - unable change to UI language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386057/netbeans-7-1-unable-change-to-ui-language/16639340#16639340) then everything will be ok, even glassfish.

Comment: This does not fix my problem. I have the same problem as the author and I don't see how language is related to git authentication not supported. Tried but can't fix.

Comment: what is your computer language and which version of Netbeans do you use?

Comment: language: English UK
Netbeans: 8.2

Comment: I don't know. You may try with Apache Netbeans 10.
Are there any setted  -J-Duser.language, -J-Duser.region parameters default in your netbeans.conf?

Comment: No, there is not until I add it as your link told me but that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since long time ago until now. Today I just find the way to fix it. Tested with Netbeans 17.
I will answer here in case somebody still have the same problem. (Thanks to the answer by @misman anyway).

On the file you are editing in your project.
Click on menu **Team** > **Remote** > **Push...**
Select **Specify Git Repository Location**.

**Remote Name:** origin and **Persist remote:** checked.
**Repository URL:** Select your repository URL from select box. Choose very carefully!
Enter your username and password, maybe checked for **Saved password**.
Click **Next**.

Select Local Branches. Usually I'll select **master** or anything look like your working branch.
Click **Next**.

Select Remote Branches. Do the same as described above but this is on your remote (Git server).
Click **Finish**.

Try to push again with menu **Team** > **Remote** > **Push to Upstream**.