# Netbeans 8.2 Git Push

Tags: git, netbeans-8, gogs

**Note: I am using Go Gits application to host my repositories**

**IDE: NetBeans 8.2**

I am trying to push my local commits to my upstream branch, it returns a message box called "Git Command Failed " with the following message:

http://UserName@DomainRedacted:3000/Redacted/Web-API-Includes.git: authentication not supported

I am using the correct username and password, I can just use the git shell but it would be nice to use netbeans in-built push functionality.

I have tried doing the following exercise in this answer: [Netbeans can pull but not push to Github: "authentication not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145029/netbeans-can-pull-but-not-push-to-github-authentication-not-supported)

Comment: I'm assuming you working in Windows. Did you tried to setup environment variable to point your git installation ??

Comment: @ThiruShetty if by Environment Variable you are talking about windows vars like PATH, then yes, I have. It should be noted that git works everywhere else on my system except for when I push from NetBeans. I was previously using PHPStorm and it worked like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for testing if removing the Username from the url can help.

In command line, go to your repo and type:

```
cd c:\path\to\my\repo
git remote set-url origin http://domainredacted:3000/Redacted/Web-API-Includes.git
```

Then try again from NetBean.

If your `git config -l` does include a `credential.helper` set to `manager`, your username/password should be cached in it.